# How to install JDK8 on Debian 10

Tags: java, javafx, java-8, debian, debian-buster

I am trying to install JDK8 on my Debian 10 virtual machine, but it seems that the only version available is JDK11. I need to run JavaFX for a school project, which is not included in JDK11. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sdkman  is your friend. Give it a try

Answer (score 0):

If you use JDK 11 and need JavaFX then you'll need to include some JavaFX libraries.

If you are using Maven you can include these dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
    <version>11</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
    <version>11</version>
</dependency>
```

If you want to include the JARs manually then you can download them from those artifacts on a Maven repository.